# Как добавить Count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Осваиваю Laravel и возникли некоторые трудности, которые я решить не смогла.

Получаю данные из БД вот таким запросом, тут что-то вроде записей.

```
DB::table('shots AS s')->join('users AS u','u.id','=','s.author_id')->
select('u.picture','u.username','s.picture AS s_picture','s.title','s.id AS shot_id')->
where('u.id',$id)->limit($limit)->
get();
```

Все работает, но мне еще нужно получить количество "лайков" к этим постам и я не понимаю как мне это сделать вместе с этим запросом.

Пыталась использовать `count` в `select`, но либо работало неккоректно, либо получала ошибку.

Вот таблица likes
`id`
`user_id`
`shot_id`

Попытка через DB::select ( мне так привычнее ) возвращает одну запись,я понимаю что что-то делаю не так - но не понимаю что именно..

```
  DB::select("SELECT u.username AS username,u.picture AS picture,s.title AS title,s.picture AS s_picture,count(l.shot_id) AS likes FROM users AS u INNER JOIN shots AS s JOIN likes AS l ON u.id=s.author_id WHERE s.id = $id AND s.id=l.shot_id LIMIT $limit");
```

Comment: А чем это поможет?

Comment: Я все данные которые хочу прекрасно получаю из БД,я просто не понимаю как мне подсчитать количество shot_id в таблице likes во время запроса.

Comment: ну раз у Вас такая *секретная структура*, то тогда делайте вложенный запрос к таблице `likes` и возвращайте количество лайков

Comment: @Bald Я думала все кто оставил хотя бы один комментарий подписываются на новые комментарии - не знала.

Сейчас попробую сделать вложенный запрос.

Comment: попробуйте следующий `sql` запрос: `select s.id, l.countLikes
from shots as s
join users u on s.author_id=u.id
join (select shot_id, Count(user_id) as countLikes from likes group by shot_id ) as l on s.id = l.shot_id`

Comment: @Bald Спасибо,но,он возвращает только те новости - в которых есть лайки,а остальные отбрасывает,это я тоже проходила:D

А во время foreach,брать ID новости,и обращатся к базе и получать количество лайков плохой вариант?

Comment: измените тип соединения с подзапросом на `left join`, намного правильней будет получить необходимую информацию за один раз, как минимум это будет быстрее

Comment: @Bald Работает,спасибо!
Но,он возвращает пустую строку,вместо нуля это можно как то изменить?
Или просто можно сделать проверочку на пустое значение,и подставить ноль,если true?

Просто,не хочу что бы это было в лучших традициях индусского кода что-ли.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42148/discussion-between-bald-and-alexandra-kott).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так мог бы выглядеть `sql` запрос к бд для получения количества *лайков*

```
select
  s.id,
  l.countLikes
from shots as s
join users u
  on s.author_id=u.id
left join (select
             shot_id,
             Count(user_id) as countLikes
           from likes group by shot_id ) as l
  on s.id = l.shot_id
```

так как `left join` возвращает `null` в случае отсутствия значения в связанной таблице то тогда в гланом запросе можно проверить значение необходимого поля и вернуть 0.

например так

```
case 
  when l.countLikes is null then 0
  else l.countLikes
end as countlikes
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно групировку еще добавить, так как count это агрегат-функция:

```
DB::table('shots AS s')->join('users AS u','u.id','=','s.author_id')->
select('u.picture','u.username','s.picture AS s_picture','s.title','s.id AS shot_id',DB::raw('count(s.id) as shots_count'))->
where('u.id',$id)->limit($limit)->
->groupBy('u.id')
get();
```

Comment: перечитайте вопрос еще раз: *Все работает, но мне еще нужно получить количество "лайков" к этим постам и я не понимаю как мне это сделать вместе с этим запросом.* без соединения с `likes` это вроде как не возможно

Comment: Не заметила двух ->->,именно на это я и натыкалась - я получаю одну запись,а количество лайков в ней равноценно количеству записей. Именно это и не смогла исправить.

Comment: Разумеется. Но это тут причем? Зачем вам знать все содержимое трех таблиц,если Вы знаете что вам нужно подсчитать количество строк где shot_id == текущий shot.id в выборке.

Comment: @AlexandraKott мне не нужно содержимое Ваших таблиц, я просил структуру, хотя бы минимально, т.е. название колонок в таблицах участвующих в запросе ;)